# how to reduce cost

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```
select *
from inv_dist_stg(table_name)
where interface_line_id in (select interface_line_id from inv_lines_stg
                            where status = 'processed'
                              and trun(creation_date) <= (trun(sysdate)-10))
```

In inv_dist_stg table already has index on column interface_line_id

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Oracle, perhaps?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. In particular, we need to know what's in `inv_dist_stg()`.

Comment: inv_dist_stg is table name

Comment: oracle are using

Comment: @LittleBitDeveloper you can mark my answer below as accepted and possibly give it a upvote others may get help from this...

Answer (score 0):

`in` would be much slow, use a  join instead.
The query is like this:

```
select *
from inv_dist_stg a,inv_lines_stg b
where a.interface_line_id=b.interface_line_id 
and b.status = 'processed' and trun(b.creation_date) <= (trun(sysdate)-10)
```

create indexes on `status` and `creation_date`

and then you are good to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. It is good that your table has a index on `interface_line_id`. Thus you can quickly access that you find in your subquery.

Now you need an index for the subquery. That is an index that should include `status` and `creation_date`. As I don't know which is more selective, you may want to try two indexes and see which one is used by the DBMS. I suppose that `trun` is a typo and means `trunc` actually. You can now either create an index on `trunc(creation_date)` or change the query to use `creation_date` without `trunc`. At last you want the index to include `interface_line_id` which is needed for the main query.

I suggest

```
select *
from inv_dist_stg
where interface_line_id in 
(
  select interface_line_id
  from inv_lines_stg
  where status = 'processed'
  and creation_date < trunc(sysdate) - 9
);
```

and

```
create index idx1 on inv_dist_stg (status, creation_date, interface_line_id);
create index idx2 on inv_dist_stg (creation_date, status, interface_line_id);
```